# Single SQL query on many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a simple database with few tables (and some sample columns):

**game** (gm_id , game_name , company , desc)

**plateform_master** (p_id , plateform_name)

**plateform_details** (pd_id, gm_id, p_id, **release_date**)

Is there a way to create single SQL query which will return all game details with multiple plateform

Comment: Yes, there's a way to do it. Join the tables, use `GROUP BY` to group all the plateforms by game ID, and use `COUNT(*)` to see how many plateforms there are.

Comment: HINT: `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. To which `posts` and `categories` are you referring yourself?
Here an example based on what I understood: Select all records from `plateform_master` and, for each of them, get its details from `plateform_details`. You can uncomment the `where` part in order to get one master record with its details. ("--" means comment in SQL)

```
select
    pm.p_id
    pd.*
from plateform_master as pm
inner join plateform_details as pd on pm.p_id = pd.p_id
-- where pm.p_id = 123
```

Sorry, my bad, it should be `left join`, not `inner join`!

With your changed requirements try this (not tested): Select all games and, for each one, get it's plateform_details and plateform_master correspondent values:

```
select
    gm.gm_id,
    gm.game_name,
    gm.company,
    pd.release_date,
    pm.plateform_name
from game as gm
left join plateform_details as pd on pd.gm_id = gm.gm_id
left join plateform_master as pm on (pm.p_id = pd.p_id AND pd.gm_id = gm.gm_id)
-- WHERE CONDITIONS
;
```

Thanks for voting. I also wanted to tell you, that you have no many-to-many relationships here. You have just one-to-many. Many-to-many means the use of a middle table between two other ones.